# How to maintain left column bottom container same size with left column width?

Tags: html, css

I have two columns, left and right column. In my left column, I have a container to be at the bottom. Always at the left bottom position. The width of this container need to be same with the left column width. I used `position: fixed` but not sure why its width doesn't contained within left column.

```css
.left {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

.terms {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-4 left'>
    Left
    <div class="terms">
      <div>Terms and Condition</div>
      <div>This website and the information contained in it are not directed to or intended for distribution or use by any person. The information presented on this website is collected, maintained and provided purely for the convenience of the site visitor/reader.</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class='col-8 right'>Right</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Check here: [```position: fixed;```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed_positioning) how it works.

Comment: remove terms CSS or use grid col-lg-*, col-sm-* bootstrap classes for different viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `position: fixed` from your class `.terms`.
The `position:fixed` will fix the text on your left at a certain position.
It would function like a sticky element. I am not quite sure if you need that.

**Edit:**
I assigned a `column` class to both columns and above that I a also added a `position:relative` with a height(you can play with the height value so you can get your ideal result) to each one of them.
On the left column, on the `terms` class, I assigned a `position: absolute` and a `bottom:0` pixels, so that it would go on the very bottom.

Moreover, I changed the way you had nested your columns. I added a `container` on top of the hierarchical DOM and a `row` above that. Following that `row`, I also added a `col-12`, `col-sm-12`, `col-lg-12` so that the column grid can occupy the 100% of its parent container.

If you want to try the snippet I created, try and expanding so you can see the real result. If it is minimized, you will not be able to see it clearly.

My last question is, how you want the mobile view to be ?

Cheers

```css
.left {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

.column{
   height: 25vh;
    position: relative;

 }

 .terms{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   font-size: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 px-0">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 left float-left column">
        Left
           <div class="terms">
             <div>Terms and Condition</div>
                <div>This website and the information contained in it are not directed to or intended for distribution or use by any person. The information presented on this website is collected, maintained and provided purely for the convenience of the site visitor/reader.</div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 right column">Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the snippet in every device on my Chrome Device Manager, and it works perfectly. Here is an image.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried but it doesn't have two columns side by side. I have added an image of how it looks like. Don't worry about the mobile version first. Thanks.

Comment: I can see your picture now. So you basically need to define the height of your columns in order to get your terms text on the bottom. I will expand my snippet a bit in order to give you a better insight.

Comment: Do I need to define the height of the column? because the height will depends on my screen size.

Comment: I would certainly use the vh css unit to work with this example. Vh stands for viewport height, which is the viewable screen's height. 100VH would represent 100% of the viewport's height. I come to realize that in your case, you can rather work with vh which is probably better than px.